# C++ Proper way to set pointer to NULL value

Tags: c++, pointers

i have quick question (i think quick). I have to check if pointer is NULL after delete data pointed by pointer. In my case i have data stored in fl->first and i want to clear this data. After clear by delete fl->first i have to check if fl->first pointer is NULL. I read a lot of posts that

```
delete fl->first;
fl->first = NULL;
```

is not good idea. And is there better way or in this case it is okey?

Comment: And did those posts specify why setting the pointer to null is a bad idea?

Comment: @UnholySheep It's not bad per se. But it can hide errors that the debug libraries can potentially find. Its also a waste of an instruction (if you decide that is important to you (looking at the embedded developers)).

Comment: @UnholySheep i found many opinions, but most of them is "Using pointer=NULL after delete can't hurt, but its better to dont do this" etc

Comment: this question is in large part to be sure that this NULL or maybe there is better way to do this (proper way). I dont want to learn bad habit

Comment: I think the point that most of the warnings are driving at is that the need to null a pointer after you delete the object it points to likely means you have muddled ownership semantics and/or aren't using appropriate smart pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the `NULL` macro in C++. Using `nullptr` literal is preferable instead. This is because the macro is ambiguous in some cases which may lead to confusion.

Besides that, you should typically avoid owning bare pointers, and thus deleting anything directly is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

`fl->first = nullptr;` is C++ way of pointing to address of 0 in most cases (it does not mean that it is always 0). Why because in `C` you have `void *` in C++ you do not. You better read [this](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/03/08/migrating-from-c-to-c-null-vs-nullptr/).

That is as simple as it gets.

Longer answer is in `void *` you can allocate memory for 1000 chars, but you can read and write `int`s into them. To avoid this and for compilers to be more type safe C++ is going away from `NULL` and `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a good idea, the reason being that it avoids crashes if you accidentally try to delete the same object again.

Example:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo(); // Create a new object
delete foo;           // Deletes the object
delete foo;           // Tries to delete an already deleted object and will therefor crash the program
```

Fix:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo(); // Create a new object
delete foo;           // Deletes the object
foo = 0;              // Sets the pointer to 0 (nullptr)
delete foo;           // Deletes nothing, the program will NOT crash
```

Comment: Better fix is to not write the second `delete foo;`. And to refactor the program in such way that it becomes impossible to do so accidentally.

Comment: @CEPB `foo = 0` and `foo = NULL` (and `foo = nullptr`) are all identical if `foo` is a pointer.  `0`, `NULL` and `nullptr` are all null pointer constants.  The thing that was being pointed out to you is that assigning the null pointer constant `0` to a pointer doesn't necessarily set all of its bits to 0.  The actual bit pattern of a null pointer can vary by platform.